# Python appending to ZipFile with file-object even with 'a' mode truncates file

Tags: python, append, zip, python-zipfile

I create an open file like this:

`self.file = open(self.gamefile, 'ab')`

Then, I write to it twice, with the ZipFile object.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(self.file, 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipf.writestr("file1.mcw", pickle.dumps(world))

with zipfile.ZipFile(self.file, 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipf.writestr("file2.mcw", pickle.dumps(world2))
```

The first write succeeds, and the file is written. As soon as it as opened again and its contents printed, it reveals that it, even despite the 'a' mode(!), has been truncated. The second write succeeds too, but the resulting zipfile only contains `file2.mcw`

What is the problem?

I know that I could put the second `writestr` into the first `with` clause, but this is a simplified example and I can't do that.

Comment: Did you try to give the path as string only, but not as file object? For me using the file object in "zipfile" failed to write anything, but the path/filename as string works

Comment: @nouseforname I've not tried using a string path, but that's not really a hack I'd like to resort to. Is there any way of getting the file object going, or am I just going to have to bite the bullet?

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to use the name of the file object, this is how i tested and it worked:

```
import zipfile

my_file = open("testing.zip", 'ab')

with zipfile.ZipFile(my_file.name, "a",  zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipf.write("data.txt")

with zipfile.ZipFile(my_file.name, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    zipf.write("data_new.txt")
```

Comment: But what if I want to use a StringIO?

Comment: Than you should show the code with that. ;) My sample works. but its possible that the file pointer is empty already and you only can read it once, by second request you have to use: file.read()).getvalue()